# C preprocessor - concatenating strings without multiple resolving

Tags: c, concatenation, stm32, preprocessor

I have a macro that points to another macro:

```
#define USART1              ((USART_TypeDef *) USART1_BASE)
#define PIPE1               USART1
```

I'm trying to add a static text which I will use as a function definition (USART1 becomes USART1_IRQHandler). I tried something like:

```
#define _IRQ(NAME)      NAME ## _IRQHandler
void _IRQ(PIPE1)(void) {
    //...
}
```

but the name resolves as PIPE1_IRQHandler instead of USART1_IRQHandler. Then I tried #NAME to get the value of PIPE1, but it had fully resolved to the most low-level representation:

```
((USART_TypeDef *) ((((uint32_t)0x40000000) + 0x10000) + 0x3800))
```

Is there any way to get USART1_IRQHandler?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

Macro arguments which participate in concatenation (`##`) and stringification (`#`) are not expanded at all in the course of replacing the macro with its definition. Consequently, it is common to pass arguments through an indirect macro so that they will be expanded fully befire being passed to the macro which concatenates or stringifies them.

There is no mechanism for partial expansion. It's basically all or nothing.

If you want to build up complicated chains of macro substitution, you need to avoid using words both as macros and as token pieces, as in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that explains everything. It was worth a try...